# Switch from iOS driver to Safari driver using appium

Tags: appium-ios

I have one application in which i can signup with linkedin,facebook, Google+ and twitter. When i click on the any button then page redirect to the safari browser and opens the login page 
I am unable to interact with Email id and password and login button in safari browser 
I am using **IOSdriver and appium version is 1.5** please help me 
How can i interact with both IOS driver and safari driver ?

Comment: what is the error u are getting?

Comment: First of all i dont know how should i start